# Using Jquery to append to all href and src attributes

Tags: javascript, jquery, github, github-pages

I need to append the name of my github repository to the beginning of all href and src attributes. Any help is appreciated.

```
<script>
  $(document).ready(function() {
    $(src).attr('src', '/Demo_App').each();
    $(href).attr('href', '/Demo_App').each();
});
</script>
```

Comment: This feels like an [XY Problem](https://xyproblem.info/). Surely before this script runs you're going to have errors or at least a [flash of unstyled content](https://webkit.org/blog/66/the-fouc-problem/). Why are all the links on your page incorrect in the first place?

Answer (score 0):

1. Select all nodes on the DOM with

```
document.getElementsByTagName('*')
```

2. Loop through them. If has src, update the src with repo name in front. If href, do the same thing but with the href instead.

```js
const repoName = '/Demo_App';

window.addEventListener('load', () => {
    const all = document.getElementsByTagName('*');

    for (const node of all) {
        const src = node.getAttribute('src');
        const href = node.getAttribute('href');

        if (src) node.setAttribute('src', `${repoName}${src}`);
        if (href) node.setAttribute('href', `${repoName}${href}`);
    }
});
```

```html
<body>
    <a href="https://google.com"></a>
    <img src="https://google.com" />
    <a href="https://google.com"></a>
    <img src="https://google.com" />
    <a href="https://google.com"></a>
    <img src="https://google.com" />
    <a href="https://google.com"></a>
    <img src="https://google.com" />
</body>
```

Answer (score 0):

use jQuery's [attr()](https://api.jquery.com/attr/) with a callback function to append values.

For example

```js
const suffix = "/Demo_App";

// all elements with `src` attribute
$("[src]").attr("src", (_, src) => src + suffix)

// all elements with `href` attribute
$("[href]").attr("href", (_, href) => href + suffix)
```

---

As always [you might not need jQuery](https://youmightnotneedjquery.com/)

```js
const suffix = "/Demo_App";

document.querySelectorAll("[src]").forEach(elt => {
  elt.src += suffix
})

document.querySelectorAll("[href]").forEach(elt => {
  elt.href += suffix
})
```